# How to use mention feature in Facebook using user account id in Facebook4jar api?

Tags: java, facebook, mention

I am trying to make simple code using java , I uses in this facebook4jar .I want to mention group members using their IDs numbers . I searched on web, and understood this " To make mention using member id,you should use this form @[id:0]".I am trying to do this.but do not work on the following code ",If condition is working . program executes code  inside if statement , and print  group members ids , Also it comments them but only words not as a mention form.

```
import facebook4j.Facebook;
import facebook4j.FacebookException;
import facebook4j.FacebookFactory;
import facebook4j.GroupMember;
import facebook4j.Post;
import facebook4j.Reading;
import facebook4j.ResponseList;
import facebook4j.auth.AccessToken;



public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FacebookException,InterruptedException {
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId("****", "***");
    facebook.setOAuthPermissions("user_friends,user_groups,user_photos,user_videos,user_birthday,user_status,user_likes,user_activities,user_location");
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken("*****", null));






         ResponseList<GroupMember> members = facebook.groups().getGroupMembers("****") ;                 

        ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebook.getFeed("******",
                new Reading().limit(25));


            for (int i = 0; i < feeds.size(); i++) {


                Post post = feeds.get(i);


                String message = post.getMessage();


                String id = post.getId();
                if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("*****")){

                for (int j =0; j < members .size(); j++){
                    GroupMember Account=members.get(j);
                    String iD="@["+Account.getId()+":]";
                    System.out.println(Account.getId());
                    facebook.commentPost(id,iD);
                              }
                          }
                     }

                      }
             }
```

Comment: You can not mention users in normal posts or comments made via API.

Comment: There is no way  to use it ?

Comment: Only Open Graph actions allow tagging/mentioning of users, when posted via API.